# System::Call to external .dll during NSIS uninstall

Tags: nsis

During the installation of my application I install a library used to export various functions to $INSTDIR. During uninstallation I want to call a function in this library to perform a task and return. Based on what I've tried so far it seems that the call to the function fails and I always get back 'error' as $0.

This is what I'm running in my uninstallation script:

```
  SetPluginUnload  alwaysoff
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  System::Call "myutils::uninstalling() i.r0"
  DetailPrint 'RETURN CODE: "$0"'
  SetPluginUnload manual
```

The few examples I've found copied the .dll to a temp directory and then ran System:Call but the library is already in $INSTDIR. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, calls to kernel32 work just great, so I'm guessing this is something silly going wrong

Comment: Have you tried the temp directory approach? Maybe you do not have permission to run the dll in the regular directory for whatever reason. Have you made sure your function input/return signatures are correct?

Comment: The function prototype is "int __stdcall uninstalling();" or is it cdecl?

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't an issue with the NSIS code, the function needed to be exported in the .def file so NSIS could resolve it sans decoration.